# bundle product not creating from admin cms

Tags: magento2.4, cms, admin-panel, bundled-product

Error:Stock with id "1" doesn't exist[image]

Comment: Whats your M2 version. Did you add any inventory specific modules.

Comment: M2.4.3
Yes there are inventory modules present in config

Comment: If thats  a custom module can you disable and check. Also we assume you have used simple products to create bundle and all product are active.

Comment: Yes I am using simple products and there is no custom module there which is interfering

Comment: can you share what all other data you have for the bundle product. Also did you manually truncate any DB or was there data migration done using some tool. As it looks like data base details are not consistent resulting in such error. Is this a fresh Magento install.

Comment: This might be the issue as it is not fresh installation

Comment: also can you tell about this issue
=>No mapping found for [stock] in order to sort on

Answer (score 0):

Can you disable MSI module as its not needed by most ecommerce store and then check. This error also gets generated due to that module and how it has been configured.